# Algorithm complexity calculated by compounding functions

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

Is there an alogrithm of complexity calculated with compounding functions ?
Let's say we have f belongs to O(n^2) and g belongs to O(n).  Is there in algoritm with complexity f(g(n)), witch is O(n^2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never met this case in real life, but you could imagine algorithms like that. For instance an algorithm that analyses another one during runtime. For instance you could have different comparison-based sorting algorithms, and an algorithm analyser that stores all comparisons done, measures the time they took, sorts them, does some statistics on them, etc. If the second algorithm has complexity `f(n)` in the number of comparisons it gets as entry, and a sorting algo has `g(n)` complexity, then running the analysis of the sorting algorithm on an input of size `n` has a total complexity of `f(g(n))`.

Anyway it's kind of a trick, since obviously `n` just isn't the same thing in `f(n)` and `g(n)`. Basically running an algorithm `algo2` on the output of an `algo1` that has roughly the same size as its complexity would work.